# Page load on the openshift server takes 2-3 mins while on local it takes 4 seconds

Tags: node.js, openshift, kubernetes-pod

We have a nods JS application which needs chromium and puppeteer core to run, the application works fine on local and openshift server only issue we see is with page load.
I am using puppeteer-core(>3.0.0) and chromium in both scenarios below code is getting executed:

```
console.log('browser built : ' + (new Date().getTime() - startTime))
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
await page.goto(URL);
console.log('page loaded : ' + (new Date().getTime() - startTime))
```

Open shift terminal Server logs:
page loaded : 140201

Local machine logs:
page loaded : 4137

Comment: Likely CPU limitations on your server. Check those.

Comment: Or dependencies. Or memory. Too little information to really know. But cpu is a good start: you are unlikely to have the unlimited capacity you would as you do running local.

Comment: @code: CPU limitations should be good : resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 400m
              memory: 2100Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 400m
              memory: 2100Mi

Comment: That's interesting. Perhaps the dependencies, as @DavidOgren mentioned?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help much on this. I'm a noob about node.js . I have no idea how much puppeteer really needs to load or what a realistic expectation is. I just wanted highlight that you are running your local tests on a laptop that probably has 6 or more cores, 12 or more hyperthreads, multiple GB of memory, and an SSD. On OpenShift you are giving it a maximum of 0.4 hyperthreads, one eighth the memory, and disk that likely has none of your libs cached. You are giving it 1/30th of the CPU you likely have on your laptop and getting roughly 1/30th of the load time.

Comment: I doubt that's the only issue, but I do sometimes have to remind people that when you give a pod 400mCPU, that really isn't a lot of compute. (It often can be enough, but it's unfair to compare it to most dev machines.)

Comment: did you get any more logs other than the specified line? if so, please include them